# Smooth Scroll to Top & Hide <div> Upon Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have it working perfectly when you click the "back to top" arrow, it hides the menu, but I just want it to do a smoothscroll to the top of the page upon click in addition to that.  You can test out what I currently have at http://rac.site44.com just readjust the width so you are in a mobile view (its responsive) and click the top-right "menu" icon to see the arrow.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="col_4 no-padding">
  <a href="/">
    <img class="logo" src="img/clear.gif" alt="RAC-Engineering - Structural Engineer Buffalo NY">
  </a>
  <a class="nav-toggle"><span class="mobile-nav-toggle mobile-only"></span></a>
  <a class="nav-toggle2 hidden"><span class="mobile-nav-toggle mobile-only"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="col_8 no-padding last">
  <nav id="nav" class="nav mobile-hide">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Estimate</a></li>
      <li class="top mobile-only"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and the JS: (Obviously I'm assuming you just need a line of code telling it to scroll to top after the `$("li.top").click(function(e) {` but I can't seem to figure it out)

```
$(function() {
  $("li.top").click(function(e) {
    $("#nav").addClass('mobile-hide');
    $(".nav-toggle").removeClass('hidden');
    $(".nav-toggle2").addClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ looks nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this on your site:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
```

You can read about `.animate()` here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/